# Multiple Groups with New Page after Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I'm Using Crystal Reports 14.1. I'm creating a report that has 3 Groups. First group is agency of the company and need separate page per agency. One agency can have more than one building, so second group is building so i need separate page here too. One building can have more than one type of employees, so i need also separate page here. What troubles me is that every group have summaries at the end, which must be on the same page. Sum per agency, per building, per type of Employee. The problem is that if one agency has one building and one type of employee, i need to show those 3 summaries at the same page.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

in section expert next to New page after click the button labeled X-2.

From there play around with a formula like.

```
if count({fieldtocount},(summarygroup} > 1
```

so that if the group only has one record it will not page break.

Comment: Hello, i need the page break, i need the summaries on the Group footer to be on the same page at the end instead on empty pages alone